# why doesnt the bool function return false?

Tags: c++

I'm soo sorry I searched for and read similar questions but couldn't understand/use them to solve my own.

Im writing a bool function within an if statement but the function doesn't seem to return false, what am I doing wrong.

My bool function just checks if there are more than one of the given number in an array:

```
bool findsame(int a[], int b){
    int k=0;
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
        if(a[i]==b){
            k++;
        }
    }
    if(k>1){
        
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}


int main()
{
const int size=20;
int a[size]={4,4};
int b=4;
if(findsame(a,b)){
    cout<<"true";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should it return false? There are 2 `4`s in the input.

Comment: oh sry, i meant it doesnt return false no matter what i change in the array. "true" is not printed out even tho it is supposed to be true.

Comment: Then edit the question to show an input that doesn't produce the output you expect.

Comment: `"true" is not printed out even tho it is supposed to be true.` The shown code prints `true`, are you sure you checked the correct output window?   `i meant it doesnt return false no matter what i change in the array` if the shown code doesn't print anything for you  (not even the `true`) and as print nothing for `false` being returned, why do you assume `false` is never returned, in that case, you would need to expect that `false` is always returned?

Comment: the unspecified values are 0 and not null? fml. Then I understand why I did wrong.

Comment: I have mentioned in the answer, the unspecified values are 0. Therefore try values for b other than 0 and 4 @ErikHNguyen. false will get printed on console.

Comment: I dont get it, it doesnt print out "true", maybe its because i have been sitting with this all night or because I am using an online compiler. Im so sorry if I am annoying, im so frustrated and fatigued.

Comment: On a side note: consider using the standard [`std::count()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) algorithm instead of a custom function.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `if (k>1) { return true; } else { return false; }` is usually written `return k>1;`.

Comment: An important note on style: the code uses the magic number `20` as the upper limit in the loop, and as the size of the array. If you change one you have to change the other. Put that definition of `size` at the top of the code, and use it as the upper limit of the loop. That way there's only one place where you set the size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you got confused why `"false"` is not getting printed on console with the function returning the  false value.

You need to add to an extra `else` statement to print `false` on the console:

```
if(findsame(a,b)){
    std::cout<<"true";
}else{
    std::cout<<"false";
}
```

Also, there are two 4 values in the array, therefore always `true` will get printed.

Try passing value of `b` other than 4 and 0.

Have a look at the following implementation where value of variable `b` is equal to `1`:

```
#include<iostream>

bool findsame(int a[], int b){
    int k=0;
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
        if(a[i]==b){
            k++;
        }
    }
    if(k>1){
        
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}


int main()
{
    const int size=20;
    int a[size]={4,4};
    int b=1;


    if(findsame(a,b)){
        std::cout<<"true";
    }else{
        std::cout<<"false";
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
false
```

**PS:** I have also tested code for the value of b = 4 and it prints true. Check and Run the code here: https://onlinegdb.com/S1LR5PtvD

Comment: if u change the b to 4 does it print out true for you cause mine doenst

Comment: Sure np, but im trying to figure out what i did wrong. The one u sent me worked. It looks exactly the same but mine just doesnt print out true.